# Execute without ./ prefix

Tags: command-line, executable

At my school's Linux cluster, its possible to run executables without the ./ prefix.  However, on my home machines, I have to do this.

I tried adding the code folder to the PATH via

`export PATH=/home/jason/Code/:$PATH`

This worked when I wanted to have some custom scripts available for autocomplete, but the compiled executables aren't showing up.

How can I set up my home machines to execute without the ./ prefix?

Comment: I'm assuming you chmod +x already and the name of the binary is not a shorter version of another binary

Comment: You're correct in that assumption.  All executables have different names from existing binaries and have executable permissions set

Answer (score 8):

Try this command instead:

```
export PATH=$PATH:.
```

This will make it so that the system will look for executables in current directory without a "./".  The command that you gave will make it so that the system will always look in that directory no matter what directory that you are in.

Comment: It is probably also worth noting that including `.` in `$PATH` is generally considered a bad idea from a security point of view.  The current directory is potentially insecure since it could be owned by some other non-privileged user.  With the default path settings, it has to be a conscious choice to execute something in the current directory.

Answer (score 2):

For your home machine you can just add a bin folder to your home dir., after a restart it will automatically be added to your path with any the recent ubuntu releases.
Then you can call your script just with the scriptname

Usually best to make sure that your scriptnames are unique as by default ~/bin will trump /usr/bin. If in doubt just add a # to the end of name. Ex. - find1

No need to have any .sh in scriptnames, note this also works with executable binaires

Comment: I like this approach.  The bin directory could also be a simple link to your ~/Code directory like you do with /usr/src/linux when compiling some modules for different kernel header versions.

Comment: A restart is a bit overkill. It should suffice to log out and back in after `~/bin` has been created. The reason for this is that the default `~/.profile` you get on Ubuntu checks if `~/bin` exists, and if it does it adds it to PATH. And `~/.profile` is read when you log in.